# Como determinar que uma div deve ocupar o espaço inteiro de uma folha A4 em PDF pelo CSS?

Tags: css, pdf

Como determinar que uma div deve ocupar o espaço inteiro de uma folha A4 em PDF pelo CSS?

Para gerar o pdf utilizo o PHP.

por exemplo

```
<div class="page">
   // conteúdo da div
</div>
```

Eu gostaria que sempre que tivesse uma div com a classe page ela ocupasse a página inteira. Alguém sabe me dizer como determino isso no CSS?

Comment: Defina melhor o título!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649943/css-to-set-a4-paper-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver pelo css da seguinte forma:

```
    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .page {
        width: 21cm;
        height: 22cm;
        padding: 2cm;
    }
```